# Can Excel with macros(VBA) turned off invoke python script

Tags: python, excel

Scenario: 2 Excel (.xlsx)sheets: INPUT, OUTPUT in same workbook. Calc set to manual.
User inputs numbers (e.g.,sales forecast).  Wants to push one key (F9, click Run or a button on the INPUT sheet).  Unknown to user a python script is called, executes (say with xlwings or openpyxl) calculates the expected sales for the year and sticks in somewhere in the OUTPUT sheet.

User then prints it out and takes it to his boss for a VIBM (Very Important Business Meeting) while the rest of the folks actually work.

Trivial with VBA involved, but many firms (especially banks) do not allow Excel sheets to run with macros allowed.  Someone read that it opens their analyses & systems to hacking.

Is this possible?  Any other ways to do it?  I could just have a command window open along side, but that gets scary when you consider the users.

Thanks,

C

Comment: Could a hyperlink in Excel to a ".bat" file executing your Python script work? There are no macros involved but hyperlinks could be disabled as well.

Comment: They don't allow VBA but they allow python?  If VBA is really a problem you could write an add-in in C#...

Comment: Hyperlink?  great idea.  Might be frowned upon but I bet it can be "hidden" -- at least from immediate view.  Thx.

Comment: No VBA?  it's just that the .xlsx is recognized .  The .xlsm requires notes from mommy and the governor.  Just like to avoid that.  Enough overhead in big companies already :-)

Comment: Hyperlink works! But can't get rid of a message about the possibility of viruses and getting cancer, etc that has to be clicked off.  Only way to disable that (that i've found) is to mess with the registry.  "Hey user buddy, you don't have to use VBA but how about a little registry work"  Right.